# GitHub API search query for non-null parameters?

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to search for the top GitHub users by # of non-forked repos, that have a public email address. When using the /search/users endpoint, it seems you must pass a query (`q=` parameter) and when I tried the following, it returned one result:

`https://api.github.com/search/users?q=%40&in:email&sort=repositories&order=desc&type=user`

I know my syntax is off by the documentation ([here](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-users/) and [here](https://help.github.com/articles/search-syntax/)) is not very helpful when constructing the URI.

Is there a way to specify that I want to select those users with the most non-forked repos *and* with non-null/empty email fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to specify that I want to select those users with the most non-forked repos and with non-null/empty email fields?

No, not possible currently using the Search API.